# Description environment, indent first line

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem, description

Is there a neat way to push the first line of an item in a `description` environment over to the right so that it is flush with the second line of the item?

I'm trying to define a LaTeX list environment that lines up with my quotes. The list items will be named, rather than numbered, and so I've been trying to use a `description` environment to do this. What I would like to get is this:

```
  Here is some regular text. Note the regular para-
graph indenting.

    Here is some text inside a default quote envir-
    onment.

Here is some regular text.

    Apples: Here is the first item.

    Oranges: Here is the second item. It wraps on-
    to a second line, and is flush with the first
    line about oranges.

Here is some more regular text.
```

I'm struggling to get this result. I've been playing around with `enumitem`, but without success  (possibly my own fault - I've never been able to get my head around the `enumitem` spacing commands). If it comes to it, I can get the result using `quote` environments rather than any kind of list, but that's obviously not ideal.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suggestion with `enumitem`. The indent-length of `2\parindent` is perhaps a little large, but that can of course be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textwidth=20em,showframe]{geometry} % yes, I borrowed this from Qrrbrbirlbel
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Description}{description}{1}
\setlist[Description]{labelindent=2\parindent,leftmargin=2\parindent}

\begin{document}
Here is some regular text.
Note the regular paragraph indenting.
\begin{quote}
    Here is some text inside a
    default quote environment.
\end{quote}
Here is some regular text.
\begin{Description}
    \item[Apples:] Here is the first item.

    \item[Oranges:] Here is the second item.
    It wraps onto a second line, and is
    flush with the first
    line about oranges.

    More paragraphing.
\end{Description}
Here is some more regular text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works too. I'm not really sure how I missed that; I thought I'd tried every combination of enumitem options. Thanks!

Incidentally, using \leftmargin rather than \parindent in the enumitem options gives the correct indent.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textwidth=20em,showframe]{geometry}
\newenvironment{Description}{\list{}{%
    \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel    % this comes from the original description environment
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}% this comes from the original quote environment
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%          this is new
    }}{\endlist}

\begin{document}
Here is some regular text.
Note the regular paragraph indenting.
\begin{quote}
    Here is some text inside a
    default quote environment.
\end{quote}
Here is some regular text.
\begin{Description}
    \item[Apples:] Here is the first item.

    \item[Oranges:] Here is the second item.
    It wraps onto a second line, and is
    flush with the first
    line about oranges.

    More paragraphing.
\end{Description}
Here is some more regular text.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]